# WP8 page Navigation problems

Tags: .net, navigation, windows-phone-8

I have a project of type Windows Phone Application (lets say namespace Project.EntryPoint) which has the App.xaml file, and I have another project with XAML files (lets say namespace Project.Views).

How can I set the Project.EntryPoint WMAppManifest to point to Project.Views/MainPage.xaml as the start page?

If that's not possible, I was thinking about adding a default MainPage to Project.EntryPoint and have a the NavigationService.Navigate in the OnNavigatedTo property. How could I construct an URI to point to Project.Views/MainPage.xaml?

These projects are actual folders, so it's:
root/Project.EntryPoint/App.xaml
root/Project.Views/Mainpage.xaml

I know this approach sounds weird, but my requirements are strict and I need an answer in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `/Project.Views;Views/MainPage.xaml` or, if that doesn't work, make the "Navigation Page" parameter of WMAppManifest.xml empty (You will see red warning text but it can be ignored); and then in the Application_Launching event add the line `App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri(Project.Views;Views/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));`